# Get parent element name in XPath

Tags: dom, xpath

I am trying to figure out how to get the name of the parent from a text node's scope.

```
//text()[name(parent)='p']
```

How can you get the name of the current node's parent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're trying to test the name, you almost had it:

```
//text()[name(parent::*)='p']
```

If you're trying to return the name:

```
name(//text()/parent::*)
```

Comment: Is this better practice than name(//text()/..)?

Comment: No, `..` is the same thing as `parent::`. I usually use `..`, but this is an old answer and who knows what I was thinking that day ;-)

Answer (score 4):

FYI, point of terminology: a text node is not an element.

Anyway, the most succinct way to select the parent of the current node is `..`

So, the name of the parent element of the current node (which could be a text node) is `name(..)`

Substituting that into your XPath expression:

```
//text()[name(..)='p']
```

But a less roundabout way to write that would be

```
//p/text()
```

(assuming the `p` elements in the document have no namespace prefix). Either way, you're selecting all text nodes that are children of elements named `p`.

Comment: Thank you for this extra explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
//text/..[@name='p']
```

This will get all parents of `<text>` nodes as long as the parent has a `name` attribute of `p`.

Comment: His terminology is confusing, but he's talking about text nodes, as opposed to `<text>` elements... And element names, as opposed to `name` attributes.